# Virtual Windows Driver proper replacement for interrupts

Tags: windows, audio, driver, interrupt

I'm working on a virtual audio/midi driver and although its already working, I'm wondering whether my implementation is ... proper..

Usually, the midi hardware triggers interrupts in the driver to send / receive / process data, however as my driver is virtual, there is no hardware that could trigger the interrupts.

The way I handled this is that I set up a DPC timer for 100ms that calls the processing / sending routines, data received is still handles via interrupt from the OS.

Now that obviously isn't quite what DPCs are for, are they. However I cannot think of another implementation that works as well.

So.. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Regards,
Xaser

Comment: Sounds ok. You don't have the actual interrupt so you emulate it, don't see anything wrong with it. You can piggyback another interrupt but I don't see any benefit in this.

Comment: Yea, however I just wonder if there alternatives to the way I emulate it now. Maybe threads, maybe something else I don't know about yet.